# MSXML 6 IServerXMLHTTPRequest.Open Fails on WIndowsEmbeddedPOSready7 & windows7 Pro

Tags: msxml6

Application that uses MSXML6 IServerXMLHTTPRequest.Open Fails when run on machines with OS WIndowsEmbeddedPOSready7 & windows7 Pro.   Works fine on Windows 8 and Windows 10.  I have installed MSXML 6 on all the machines.   The application creates the object ok on all machines but the open fails on machines running OS
WindowsEmbeddedPOSready7 & Windows7 Pro

Comment: This same application successfully uses IServerXMLHTTPRequest.Open to communicate with a web site that is outside the LAN  . The url is "https://app.teamsupport.com/api".  The  IServerXMLHTTPRequest.Open that fails is trying to establish a connection with a machine that is on the LAN with the same IP address scheme.

Comment: The URL that can be opened by IServerXMLHTTPRequest.Open is ""https://app.teamsupport.com/api"

Comment: The URL that works starts with https:\\,  each time i save the comment it removes the https:.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a URL of http://10.1.1.61:10009 is fine for windows 8,  windows 10 but on windows 7 and POSReady7 and XP SP3 the open will fail.

If you add a / to the end the open worls on all OSs.

So http://10.1.1.61:10009/ solves all the problems.  The cryptic result from the open of

lResult& = OBJRESULT returns -2147012891 does not tell you much.  It was pointed out to me that if you search the web, but use the hexadecimal value for the search you can find out the error means Invalid URL?